# Editing part of UITextview

Tags: swift, uitextview

I have a `UITextview` and i am not able to change the cursor position to the middle. If i try to do so it goes to the 0th position. I am not able to find any property/toggle to fix it. I have set `.allowsEditingTextAttributes = true` 
but that does not help. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
extension UITextView {
    func setCursor(position: Int) {
       let position = self.position(from: beginningOfDocument, offset: position)!
       selectedTextRange = textRange(from: position, to: position)
    }
}
```

Comment: Force unwrapping is unsafe, better to use guard: `guard let position = self.position(from: beginningOfDocument, offset: position) else { return }` - Please note that this wil fail silently when the position is not found

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks